# Serving a WSGI app endpoint in a separate thread?

Tags: python, networking, flask, wsgi, gunicorn

I have a WSGI application (it's a Flask app, but that should be irrelevant, I think) running under a Gunicorn server at port 9077. The app has a /status endpoint, which is supposed to report 'OK' if the app is running. If it fails to report OK within a reasonable time, the whole container gets killed (by Kubernetes).

The problem is this: when the app is under very heavy load (which does happen occasionally), the /status endpoint can take a while to respond and the container sometimes gets killed prematurely. Is there a way to configure Gunicorn to always serve the /status endpoint in a separate thread? Perhaps even on a different port? I would appreciate any hints or ideas for dealing with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never worked with Gunicorn, and im not sure if it supports this feature.

But with [uWSGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/uwsgi/), when i know that the app is going to be under a heavy load,
i run `uwsgi` with `--processes` (can also run in multithread mode or both)

uWSGI just spins up multiple instances of the flask app and act as a load balancer, no need for different ports, `uwsgi` takes care of everything.
You are not bound by `GIL` anymore and your app uses all the resources available on the machine.

[documentation about uWSGI concurrency](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#adding-concurrency-and-monitoring)

[a quick tutorial on how to setup a flask app, uWSGI and nginx](http://www.technopy.com/deploying-production-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx.html) (you can skip the nginx part)

here is an example of the config file i provide.

```
[uwsgi]
module = WSGI:app
master = true
processes = 16
die-on-term = true
socket = 0.0.0.0:8808
protocol = http
```

`uwsgi --daemonize --ini my_uwsgi_conf.ini`

I can easily achieve 1000 calls/sec when its running that way.
hope that helps.

ps: Another solution for you, just spin up more containers that are running your app.
And put them behind [`nginx`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) to load-balance

Comment: This uWSGI solution looks fabulous, thanks! Just to clarify, do you actually run plain uwsgi in prod, without nginx in front of it?

Comment: @JordanDimov `uWSGI` is production ready (and more mature then Gunicorn). `nginx` just adds more flexibility, like redirections, reverse proxy, header stuff, ssl, etc... If you don't need advanced features just use`uWSGI` it will be more then enough. please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful.